# sum values from multiple ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

im trying to get the total value of the data returned by the ajax requests, but it is showing total:0 because it is executing the totalRev before completing the ajax requests.

```
var totalRev = 0;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cloudmobi.php",
            data: {action: 'cloudmobi'},
            dataType:'JSON', 
            success: function(response){
                document.getElementById('cloudmobi').innerHTML = response.cloudmobi;
                console.log(response.cloudmobi);
                var cloudmobi = parseInt(response.cloudmobi);
                console.log('CLOUDMOBI:'+cloudmobi);
                totalRev += cloudmobi;

            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mobusi.php",
            data: {action: 'mobusi'},
            dataType:'JSON', 
            success: function(response){
                document.getElementById('mobusi').innerHTML = response.mobusi;
                console.log(response.mobusi);
                var mobusi = parseInt(response.mobusi);
                totalRev += mobusi;
                console.log('MOBUSI:'+mobusi);

            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "appnext.php",
            data: {action: 'appnext'},
            dataType:'JSON', 
            success: function(response){
                document.getElementById('appnext').innerHTML = response.appnext;
                console.log(response.appnext);
                var appnext = parseInt(response.appnext);
                totalRev += appnext;
                console.log('APPNEXT:'+appnext);

            }
        });
        console.log('TOTAL:'+totalRev);
```

I do not want to use async because the whole purpose of using ajax here is to load the site fast then dynamically load the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be *far* better to send all the data in a single request so you can do the sum on the server and send it in a single property in the response.

Assuming, for whatever reason, you cannot do that, then you could instead store all the promises from the AJAX requests and then execute your code after all of them have completed and added their values to an array. Then you can sum the array. Something like this:

```js
var values = [];
var promises = [
  $.ajax({
    // ajax settings...
    success: function() {
      values.push(parseInt(response.cloudmobi), 10);
    }
  }),
  $.ajax({
    // ajax settings...
    success: function() {
      values.push(parseInt(response.mobusi), 10);
    }
  }),
  // Nrequests...
];

$.when.apply(this, promises).done(function() {
  var sum = values.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
  // work with sum here...
});
```

Comment: all of the data is taken from bad APIs, load times were above 8 seconds, having one php file for each api and requesting the data with ajax is far faster, I will try this right now.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery "[when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)" solves your problem:

```
$.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {
    console.log( v1 ); // "Fish"
    console.log( v2 ); // "Pizza"
});
```